# Como adicionar corretamente mais de um ion-radio em um template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Estou tendo problemas ao adicionar mais de um ion-radio em um template.

Tenho uma tela com um ion-radio que está funcionando de acordo. Porém preciso adicionar mais alguns e estou encontrando problemas.

Quando eu alterno a marcação de opções do primeiro radio, funciona de acordo.
Porém caso eu marque uma opção do outro radio, ele está desmarcando a seleção do(s) demais, O que fazer para resolver?

Aqui estão os códigos que estou utilizando:

```
<ion-radio 
     ng-repeat="report in config.relatorios" 
     ng-value="report.value" 
     ng-model="config.selecao.relatorio">    

     {{report.name}}

</ion-radio>

<ion-radio 
    ng-repeat="menu in config.menu" 
    ng-value="menu.value" 
    ng-model="config.selecao.menu">

    {{menu.name}}

</ion-radio>


 vm.menu = 
        [
            { name: 'Grid (Quadrado)', value: 'quadrado' }, 
            { name: 'Lista', value: 'lista' }, 
            { name: 'Grid (Circulo)', value: 'circulo' }
        ];

 vm.relatorios = 
         [
            { name: 'Diário', value: 'diario' }, 
            { name: 'Mensal', value: 'mensal' }
        ];

 vm.selecao = {
                menu: 'lista',
                relatorio: 'diario',
            };
```

Comment: Adicionei a propriedade e resolveu. valeu mesmo, Se quiser adicionar como resposta, eu marco como correta dai =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tive esse problema e consegui resolver simplesmente colocando a propriedade name nos ion-radio.

`<ion-radio ng-repeat="menu in config.menu" ng-value="menu.value" ng-model="config.selecao.menu" name="1"> 
    {{menu.name}} 
</ion-radio>`